# ASP.NET MVC Quick Tutorials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to learn basic concepts of asp.net mvc in 1 or 2 days. Which books, sites, tutorials or smth else can you reccomend me?

Comment: To add to the answers: don't learn ASP.NET MVC 1 or 2. They're completely obsolete. Also, be wary of any material you find that doesn't specify the version; it could be ASP.NET MVC 1 stuff that doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/mvc has a bunch of pretty good "Getting Started" tutorials...

And the "Gu" gives a pretty good run through here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

Answer (score 3):

you should check this one: [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

there are plenty of resources, videos, samples and articles.

that is surely the best way to start, take some time to check those videos, starting from the shortest ones then moving to more detailed ones. Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the previously provided answers cover some of the great sources you can start with

The following conference session videos are great the start with also :

**MVC 3 – 101 by Scott Hanselman** : 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DevDays/DevDays-2011-Netherlands/Devdays002

**ASP.NET MVC 3 @:The Time is Now by Phil Haack** : 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM03

**ASP.NET + Packaging + Open Source = Crazy Delicious by Scott Hanselman** : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/FT01

And there are so many out there on [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com)