# Why don't I have Routes.MapRoute in global.asax in an MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, global-asax

I have a problem with setting default route in my Asp.net MVC project.  My `global.asax` doesn't have `Routes.MapRoute`, it just has the code bellow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace razor
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's in `RouteConfig.cs` in your `App_Start` folder

Comment: @Jonesy: I guess it was you remvoing your comment so fast. Thanks. Incorporated in the answer.

Comment: This is a very poor question.  You have many utilities to find out what is going on.  You could first look at the code you posted and ask your self, hey what does `RouteConfig.RegisterRoute()` do (F12 to the code).  You could ctrl+shift+F and find in files where a `.MapRoute()` method is executed. etc, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the introduction of ASP.NET MVC 4 with Areas, etc. they were all moved to the `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` method. So go there and change your routes!

You can find that class in the `RouteConfig.cs` file in your `App_Start` folder.

Comment: when i run my view i see this error:
{
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446

}
i work in visual studio 2010..doesnt need to install IIS??

Comment: That really needs more info than an error message. Try the advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293778/asp-net-mvc-resource-cannot-be-found-error and google for the error message. If it doesn't help, ask a new question.