# How to fix the Url (~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml) when run from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using MVC 4 VS 2012 Express for Web to develop a site. Usually when I directly run from the view, for example Index View in Home Controller, I got 'http://localhost:62335/' on the url address bar, but now I got http://localhost:62335/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

I don't change the routing on RouteConfig class, as you can see in the code below

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Why this could happen and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean _when I directly run from the view_? Are you generating a link in a view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, open Index.cshtml and press "F5" to run the web

Comment: OK, See Ash's answer (note you don't actually need to type anything in - if the textbox is left blank it will go to the default)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think it's different from the common behaviour, when I open another view for example User Index page and press F5 it will automatically open the User Index page.

Answer (score 6):

Try to call the controller instead :

```
http://localhost:62335/Home/
```

Go to your project's properties and set the start page property.

- Go to the project's Properties
- Go to the Web tab
- Select the Specific Page radio button
- Type in the desired url in the Specific Page text box i.e. http://localhost:62335/Home/

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work http://localhost:62335/http://localhost:62335/Home/. I don't want to make it static. I mean it always direct to http://localhost:62335/Home. If you open another view, for example ~/Views/User/Index.cshtml when you click F5 to run the web it should open the User Index page http://localhost:62335/User

Comment: MVC is supposed to work with controllers and not based on views. This example was just to give a quick fix mate. This is not a solution. You must set a default route and controller method must handle the calls. Not views.

Comment: Yes you're right and I know it, but it's weird, usually when I develop in MVC and want to test the result, I just press F5 and automatically IE will display the corresponding page. Actually I wonder why there can be "Views" words in the Url

Comment: Views corresponds to the folder structure here mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer to make a clear answer and find it easier

As answered in [ASP.Net MVC – Resource Cannot be found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293778/asp-net-mvc-resource-cannot-be-found-error)

You should go to `Project Properties` then `Web Tab` and leave it blank.

I'm wondering why we should fiax it manually!

Answer (score 0):

1. Project rigth click > Properties
2. click to Web
3. Select "Current Page" and Save

[image]